# Reliable Key-Value File-Based Storage with/without XA Transactions

Tags: java, transactions, key-value-store, nosql

### **Problem**

I'm currently implementing a solution for one pretty old system, which needs a **lightweight** key-value **file-based** (a value for a key is stored as a file) storage with simple ConcurrentHashMap-like operations: put(), delete(), get() and listAll() operations.
It has to privide an ability to have concurrent read and write operations with a fully-featured transactional behavior (ACID + repeatable read isolation).

*Seems like this component should look pretty similar to the TableFS...*

### **Approach**

An initial idea is to take a lightweight embeddable persistent key-value storage  and use it to store a metadata for the value files located in a file system (file key, file path, size, other attributes...). Also, it should provide a quick file searching engine, based on indexes. So that, such storage plays a role of a register...

I have been searching for quite a while for such the key-value storage that can meet the following requirements:

- Open source;
- Embeddable;
- Provide a support for Java maps and collections;
- Machine crash/power-off tolerance (write-ahead logs and other approaches);
- Providing ACID transaction;
- Being a read-write storage (comparing to the read-only PalDB).

and came up with the MapDb and LevelDb options.

As far as I need to ensure the concurrency resolution for those read/write user transactions, I need to establish global XA transactions, involving the key-value storage and a file system. For the file system there are the XADisk and Jakarta Commons-Transactions transaction systems, also for the global archestration there is the Atomikos Essintials transaction manager.

However, I cannot find any article that explains how to configure the MapDB or LevelDB with an XA transaction manager...

### Questions

Could you please suggest on the following?

1. whether my approach makes sense or there are some well-known solutions/implementations for the described problem?
2. what pitfall can you see in this task/approach?
3. are there any resources that describe how to configure such key-value storages for participating in xa transactions?

### Updates

There is another database - SQLite - which can be integrated with Atomikos. It does not mimic Java collections, but it is pretty easy to emulate all the opeations manually. The only pitfall that I can see for now, is the way of resolving concurrent key modifications by concurrent transactions (lost update problem). Seems like there would be a requirement of writing a kind of stored procedure with the test-and-set feature based on a key's timestamp...

Comment: did you look at wiredtiger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, I worked out an idea for implementing my task, even without XA transactions, file locks and other over-complications.

If somebody is interested, please have a look at my project at GitHub, [following this link](https://github.com/Dmitry-Kober/SmartMap). The description would be added soon to the GitHub project. Hope, for now, the code is self-explanatory.